# Is it possible to serialize an array so that its elements aren't wrapped in a tag for the array?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have the following `Rule` and `Ruleset` classes:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(OrRule))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(AndRule))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(EmptyRule))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(MatchRule))]
public class Rule {}

[XmlType("Or")]
public class OrRule
{
    public Rule[] Operands { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("And")]
public class AndRule
{
    public Rule[] Operands { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Empty")]
public class EmptyRule {}

[XmlType("Match")]
public class MatchRule
{
    public string Regex { get; set; }
}

public class Ruleset
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayElement(typeof(OrRule))]
    [XmlArrayElement(typeof(AndRule))]
    [XmlArrayElement(typeof(EmptyRule))]
    [XmlArrayElement(typeof(MatchRule))]
    public Rule[] Rules { get; set; }
}
```

(I hope I got everything right - this is a radically simplified example and not the actual code.) These get serialized to something like this:

```
<Ruleset Name="PasswordEmptyAllowed">
  <Rules>
    <Or>
      <Operands>
        <Empty />
        <And>
          <Operands>
            <Match Regex="\d" />
            <Match Regex="[a-záéíóöőúüű]" />              
            <Match Regex="[A-ZÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ]" />
          </Operands>
        </And>
      </Operands>
    </Or>
  </Rules>
</Ruleset>
```

The extra `<Rules>` and `<Operands>` tags are pretty ugly in my opinion, and they hurt readability. Is there a way to elimiate them?

Like this:

```
<Ruleset Name="PasswordEmptyAllowed">
  <Or>
    <Empty />
    <And>
      <Match Regex="\d" />
      <Match Regex="[a-záéíóöőúüű]" />              
      <Match Regex="[A-ZÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ]" />
    </And>
  </Or>
</Ruleset>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[XmlElement("Rule")]
public Rule[] Rules {
```

Comment: This works when serializing but not when deserializing. Weird, isn't it? (egyébként én is magyar vagyok :))

Comment: Actually what I tried is `[XmlElement(typeof(OrRule))]`, `[XmlElement(typeof(AndRule))]` etc. because I need to have different tag names for the different subclasses of `Rule`. The XML I get after serializing is perfect but deserializing the same threw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to manipulate the XML your self before/after it's converted to Object/XML.

But think about what you are trying to do.

I would like to disagree with you on tags being ugly. I think they help in readability, they keep child tags together.

imagine a tag with two such collections without a wrapping tag. With your approach, they can easily be mixed up together making them harder to read and serialize/deserialize.

### Example:

```
<And>
  <Match Regex="\d" />
  <Replace From="123" To="ABC" />
  <Match Regex="[a-záéíóöőúüű]" />              
  <Replace From="_" To=" " />
  <Match Regex="[A-ZÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ]" />
  <Replace From="-" To="#" />
</And>
```

Instead of

```
<And>
  <Matches>
      <Match Regex="\d" />
      <Match Regex="[a-záéíóöőúüű]" />              
      <Match Regex="[A-ZÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ]" />
  </Matches>
  <Replaces>
      <Replace From="123" To="ABC" />      
      <Replace From="_" To=" " />
      <Replace From="-" To="#" />
  </Replaces>
</And>
```

You decide which one is readable and maintainable.

Think about what can go wrong with the approach you suggest and why `XmlSerializer` in `.Net Framework` promotes the current implementation.

Comment: I thought about what I'm trying to do and I'm pretty sure this is the most convenient and readable approach. These rules are for a content validator that checks user input against a predefined ruleset read from the XML I'm trying to generate here. The tags inside the rulesets can be thougth of expressions that evaluate to either true or false and can be combined using logical operators. I don't think having an extra tag for the operands helps readability and it's also unintuitive (the ruleset xml's will be frequently edited by the sysadmins and I'm pretty sure these would cause confusion).